# What are best practices for sharing and accessing Vault secrets?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

When one follows [a Hashicorp's Vault demo](https://www.vaultproject.io/#/demo/1), one has to issue `vault init -key-shares=1 -key-threshold=1` at a certain moment that generates a `key 1` and `root token`:

```
Key 1: ABC
Root Token: XYZ
```

If person A generates a secret by executing `vault write secret/hello value=world` how could person B check on his/her computer the value of `secret/hello`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming person B has a role which also allows them access to the path `secret/hello`, then they would simply run `vault read secret/hello` from their own machine.

If you're following the demo, I think the vault server will be on your local machine? So if someone else is to connect to it they would need to set `VAULT_ADDR` to point to the IP where the server is running.